# Dynamic SQL in SQL Server: Executing a string through sp_sqlexec @string VS using a pure SQL query - why does stored string not work?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

```
DECLARE @Description NVARCHAR(128) = N'MS_Description'
--Just for good measure
SET @Description = N'MS_Description'
```

The first statement is me trying to use `sp_sqlexec` by storing my SQL with dynamic parameters in a string:

```
SELECT @query = @query + 'SELECT * FROM TABLE 
                          WHERE COLUMN = ' + @Description
EXEC sp_sqlexec @query
```

The above doesn't work, I get the following error:

> Invalid column name 'MS_Description'

When I debug through this, the statement is exactly the same as the below query, that works and returns the results that I want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE column = @Description
```

Could someone please explain the difference and why the below works if it is the exact same thing that's stored in `@query`? Thank you

Comment: sp_sqlexec? Where did you find that? That hasn't been supported in a LONG time. Like a REALLY long time. sql 6.5 or so. You should be using sp_executesql for dynamic sql and then you can parameterize it. But from what you posted you don't seem to need dynamic sql anyway.

Comment: Completely agree with @SeanLange. This doesn't need to be dynamic SQL, however, if for some reason (unknown to us) it has to be, you **must** parametrise it. Also, to add to his point: [sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: But to answer your question, you are using a variable when you write the query but in your dynamic sql you need to add '' on both sides of your variable. To debug this you should print/select your dynamic string which will demonstrate quickly where the problem is. But seriously, I am curious how you even found sp_sqlexec. It hasn't been in the documentation for at least 20 years, which is about the last time it was supported. To be honest I was surprised it is still available, and even more surprised it still seems to work.

Comment: Then again looking at the definition it just converts the text parameter to nvarchar(max) and executes it with exec. Not sure why MS didn't just remove it instead of making it a wrapper to another unsafe way of executing dynamic sql.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, if I remember right, I was trying to find sp_executesql, and must've used intellisense to find sp_sqlexec instead. Appreciate the responses, I got it working with sp_executesql instead. And yes, @Larnu, I did need to get it working with dynamic SQL, I should've added that into my question, thank you for picking up on that, and that link to the documentation has been very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the first query is that you're not adding your quotes back in. It treats the + as a concat, so your statement ends up being

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE 
 WHERE COLUMN = MS_Description
```

We know this won't work, as MS_Description should be 'MS_Description'

What you need to do for the top one to work is

```
SELECT @query = @query + 'SELECT * FROM TABLE 
                      WHERE COLUMN = ''' + @Description + ''''
```

Comment: Not quite. You need to use double single quotes.

Comment: Hah! Good catch. Wrote about escaping, then forgot to escape it in my answer. Doh!

Comment: Thank you kindly for the response.

As a sidenote for those who are interested, I was using 'sp_sqlexec' which is very old, as far as I've been made aware.

sp_executesql is a far better, more modern alternative.